# Whether the attached graphs are isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

[image: $G_1$]

[image: $G_2$]

Whether these two graphs are nonisomorphic? 
They have same number vertices, same regularity, they are cospectral (means: they have same same set of adjacency eigenvalues). I have taken powers of their adjacency matrices and observed that each number in its entries is appearing the same number of times. So whether I could conclude, they are isomorphic!

Comment: There are only 9 vertices, can't you just brute force it?

Comment: We have $C_4 \dot \cup K_1$ and $K_{1,4}$ are cospectral but not isomorphic. Cospectral is necessary but not sufficient for isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: $G_1^C$]

[image: $G_2^c$]

Clearly the complements are isomorphic so both the graphs in Figure-1 and Figure-2 are isomorphic.